# memory allocation using runtime type information

Tags: c++, typeid

I got to know about run-time type information in c++. This can be accomplished with 
typeid keyword in c++.

```
int main()
{
        //these two where user-defined class
        Complex x;
        Point3D y;

        const type_info& s = typeid(x);

        cout<<typeid(y).name()<<endl; //works...(1)
        cout<<s.name()<<endl;         //works...(2)

        Complex * tp = new s[10];     //does not work...(3)
}
```

As marked in the code, I was successful in printing out types of the data objects as in (1) and (2).

Now I wish to allocate memory by using type_info/typeid. Could anyone do this? Is it even possible. I do not have any virtual functions.

Can such a feat be accomplished by any other way. I do not want to use virtual functions as it has a negative effect on code vectorization.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The obvious way to create an array of ten `Complex` objects is with `new Complex[10];`; why do you want something else?

Comment: use decltype found in c++11. It sounds like the type of the value will always be known at compile time.

     `auto tp = new decltype(x)[10];`

No, this wont work in runtime systems, but depending on the application, you won't need to.

Comment: how about if (typeid(y).hash_code == ) .... new y[]... else .. new x[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. What you are looking for is a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

Here is an example of such a factory. Suppose you have these types:

```
class point_t
{
};

class complex_t : public point_t
{
};

class point3d_t : public point_t
{
};
```

You can define the following factory:

```
typedef point_t* (*makeptr)();

class point_factory
{
   static point_t* make_complex()
   {
      return new complex_t();
   }

   static point_t* make_point3d()
   {
      return new point3d_t();
   }
   static std::map<std::string, makeptr> _map;
public:
   static void init()
   {
      _map.insert(make_pair(typeid(complex_t).name(), &point_factory::make_complex));
      _map.insert(make_pair(typeid(point3d_t).name(), &point_factory::make_point3d));
   }
   static point_t* make_point(const type_info& type)
   {
      std::map<std::string, makeptr>::iterator pos = _map.find(type.name());
      if(pos != _map.end())
         return (*(pos->second))();
      return NULL;
   }
};

std::map<std::string, makeptr> point_factory::_map;
```

And use it like this:

```
point_factory::init();
point_t* p = point_factory::make_point(typeid(point3d_t));
```

Comment: the thing is that, i wud hav multiple user defined types. thtz i need a dynamic way of memory allocation

Comment: @user1703586, than your users should define a factory for their type, and register that factory somehow so that you may call it.

Comment: more info/code on factories? is there an implementation of factory u knw of which wud be helpful for me?

Answer (score 0):

In your code `s` is not a type, it is a reference to an object.
A type is syntactic construct, that exists only during compilation, and when the program is compiled to native code, most if not all type information is lost!

Comment: ya i knw (3) is wrong. the idea is that i want to allocate memory based on the data type which is obtained with typeid()

Comment: Well, RTTI is real-time type information, so your statement is wrong. Without it, you'll have no dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: I think, @AntonGuryanov, that you misunderstood what I meant by type.
In native code, there are no types. Types exist only during compilation so that the compiler can associate methods with objects, allocate proper stack frames and call proper constructors.

Comment: n btw is it possible to typecast void* into run-time type info?

Comment: You're right, **types** exist only during compilation, but **type information** is saved in the native code. I just wanted to correct that.

Comment: @user1703586, no, it's not posible.
You can only cast to types (and that means that the type must be known at compile time). Perhaps it will be more prudent if you expanded your question with information about what you are trying to accomplish, so that we may better help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any virtual functions, you don't have RTTI, so `typeid(x).name()` is always `Complex`, and you can simply write

```
Complex *tp = new Complex[10];
```

Answer (score -1):

If the code was in a templated function you could probably do something similar to that. But after looking at the docs for type_info, I don't think it will work for what you want.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/type_info/

Now C# can do what you want using reflection. But since you native C++ has no reflection you are out of luck.

Comment: No. If you're using C++11, you can, however, access to [quite a lot](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) of compile-time type information. E.g. it's possible to check whether a class has a method with specific name, accepting specific types as arguments.